# "First Answer" not a first answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

I was reviewing [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5455439) today and I came upon a supposedly "First Answer" by a new user, to look over. Only problem? It wasn't the user's first answer at all!

Am I missing something?

**Supposedly "First Answer"**

[image]

**The actual answer when I clicked on the link provided on the review page.**

[image]

As you can see, the two answers appear to be completely different. Especially note the time answered. The first says it was answered 2 hours ago, but the other one was a few days ago. What is going on?

Comment: Look at the top of the page: Review audit passed just now:

Comment: @JohnPalmer You're absolutely right! I had no idea there was such a thing, let alone what it is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, now I feel stupid. Apparently it was a review audit as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).

But hey, at least I was paying attention, right!

Comment: Yep! And the biggest part of what audits shall do is catching those not paying attention, like at all.