# First Post Answer of a user- not really his first time answering

Tags: bug, review-queues

While going through the First Post review, I came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16229987)
from a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3655437/techseeko) which is already a member for 3 years and has (at the time of this post) 17 answers under his belt.

Might this be a bug?

Comment: That's an audit, not a real first post.

Comment: So do what you think is right there

Comment: @Floern I mean no offense to anyone. I don't understand.. it says on my end "Review|First Posts" and "This is the first answer posted by a new user. Help them learn to use the site by reviewing their post.". I don't think I can provide any help for this user as he doesn't seem to be new.

Comment: See here: ["First Answer" not a first answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267643/first-answer-not-a-first-answer)

Comment: ..and, I failed the test. Thanks, I got it.